# Wordpress Multisite IIS web.config file

Tags: wordpress, iis, wpmu

I've set up a wordpress network with the sub-domain feature in an IIS server.  While the process is difficult because IIS doesn't support wildcards very easily, I have gotten wildcard subdomains to work in the past.

When I create a site in the network and try to access it, I just get an error saying the site can not be found.  Not a 404 from IIS, but like the DNS record could not be found.

I have DNS set up on the server with the wildcard A name record, in the same instance as two other sites where the wildcard redirect works.  I even tried giving it a Cname record, but it's still not finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with DNS setting from the name server.  Counterpart stated they had made change when they had not.